# how to display pound symbol in iOS5

Tags: ios5

I have program where in i have to display the currencies. I need to know how to display the pound and euros sign on the view. i need a step by step procedure for doing it. Please help.
Thanks all.

Comment: It's easy just add a label and then add symboles to it's text property from edit > Special Characters.. and then from popup window select currency symbols, which contains all the currency symbols. If still want more help ask for it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy just add a label and then add symboles to it's text property from **edit > Special Characters..** and then from popup window select currency symbols, which contains all the currency symbols.

This will work for xib files and also for .m (ie in coding) fiels, too.

[image]

[image]

If still want more help ask for it :)